# Post Object with query parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm using restkit in my project and trying to post object to our rest api server with postObject request:

```
postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
```

Restkit documentation [says](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:): **parameters** - the parameters to be reverse merged with the parameterization of the given object and set as the request body.

But what if I want my parameters to be like in `getObject` so "The parameters to be encoded and appended as the query string for the request URL."

What is the idea behind? Why Restkit developers made parameters to be merged with body? If I want them to be merged with body I would make those fields in my model class to be mapped in body. 
Is there any way to make request with query parameters to be added to url and body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's like an unwritten rule for working restful API's. Whenever you use GET you just reach to an endpoint with required query parameters. You are just giving the key parameters to reach (im)mutable data. For example;

```
.../accounts?name={name}
```

There is just no need to send a whole body for this when all backend needs is just an id to search.

There is nothing like you can't send body within GET or use POST with query parameters but these API's are tend to work like that.

Whenever you POST something to a restful API you are actually saying that I want to create something on your side with this given data. Representing objects are easier with a body if you are going to submit that value to the backend.

Also there is something called JSON-rpc. I might be wrong but it basically use POST for everything. You are even using for GET-like actions and sending body within. So you can even do GET actions with POST and bodies.

It's not a must but easier to work with this representation.

Comment: It's supposed to be restful, but most of api servers I saw have requests like I described. I really don't believe restkit has no way to do this without string format or something like that.